# unable to open microsoft browser in VM and not able to download web platform installer

Tags: azure, window, virtual-machine, azure-vm

I am using the bs1 instance window virtual machine for the setup of PHP Project but when I am connecting with the RDP. It connected successfully but when I am trying to access the Microsoft Edge browser it is not responding due to which I am unable to install and download the web platform installer.

Can you suggest to me what I am doing wrong ??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Selected VM B1s is of very less size. It has only 1 core CPU and 1GB RAM as shown in the below image.

This may be the reason why you face delay or cannot access the MS Edge. You will also face difficulties to create project and install web platform installer as the VM has low configuration.

[image]

Would suggest you to please try upgrading your VM size to a better configuration as per your requirement and try accessing the edge.

Reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/virtual-machines/series/